# Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to design a dynamic UI for my application so in screens with more than `500dp` width it  will show 2 fragment and otherwise it shows a single fragment.

Here is my layout files:

layout/activity_main:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

layout-w500dp/main_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="ir.focusmag.focus.PostsFragment"
        android:id="@+id/posts_frag_container"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_posts" />

    <fragment android:name="ir.focusmag.focus.PhotosFragment"
        android:id="@+id/photos_frag_container"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_photos" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in `MainActivity.java` there is a check to see whether `frag_container` is present or not and if it's there it will load the `PostsFragment` into it:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
        if (findViewById(R.id.frag_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            firstFragment = new PostsFragment();
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragm_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frag_container, firstFragment).commit();


        }


    }
```

And there is a Listener for clicking on a post to replace the fragment with the details fragment.

The important point here is if we're being restored from a previous state it doesn't do anything.

In usual scenarios this method works but if the user stars the application in landscape mode ( screen width > 500dp ) MainActivity checks for `frag_container` and as it's not there It will do nothing and then the user will rotates the device to portrait mode and as the `savedInstanceState` is not null anymore nothing will be loaded into `frag_container`.

If I remove the check for `savedInstanceState`, whenever the user rotates the device PostsFragment will be loaded and it's not wanted. for example the user is checking the details and rotates the device and it shows the posts instead of the details.

What can I do to stop this kind of behavior?

I'm following [Android Developer's tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/) to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is a little bit outdated. If you just started playing with Android and want to see how to handle things modern way, watch [Developing Android Apps](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853) video course from Google by Google. They will show you how to deal with Master/Detail pattern properly. If you would like to jump immediately to the code, start your Android Studio and create new `Activity` with the wizard and pick Master/Detail form.

Your new activity's onCreate() method would look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
        // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;

        // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
        // 'activated' state when touched.
        ((ItemListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.item_list))
                .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }

    // TODO: If exposing deep links into your app, handle intents here.
}
```

Comparing to your current approach, this time for single pane mode fragment is added within XML layout so you don't have to bother with unexpected behavior. You will also see there how [layout aliases](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters) works.

I know it's not a simple answer you may expect buy it may be the last moment for your application to apply this change. I really encourage you to do it.

If this change is not an option for you consider modifying single pane layout and include fragment there instead adding dynamically. Probably, at the moment, your are not benefit from dynamic fragment at all anyway.

Comment: Thank you! That was driving me crazy! I thought that Android developers tutorials were up to date.

Comment: To be honest Android Developer page is one of the best documentations I have ever seen and they really try to keep it up to date. Unfortunately, in a real world it's not that easy and all materials that is not "wrong" just "old" land to the end of the queue for updates. My advice is to search solutions in several places for single dilemma. At least give it a try and if you are sure that there is nothing newer start your coding.